# how to unchecked check box generated by ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have `check boxes` in my application. I put it inside `directive`. Now the problem is I want to unchecked any of checked boxes from controller. I am able to `unchecked` all `checkboxes` but not particular one. Is there any way to tell the `directive` to unchecked the `checkbox` by setting `model value to false`.

DIRECTIVE:

```
 .directive('filterCheckbox', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {

            link:function(scope,element,attrs){
                var temp = '<div class="check-box pull-left">' +
                    '<span  class="ft" data-ng-class="{\'active\': '+attrs.ngModel+' ,\'inactive\':'+!attrs.ngModel+'}"></span>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="'+attrs.ngModel+'" class="hide" data-ng-click="getFilteredAttrs(this)">'

                element.html($compile(temp)(scope));

               scope.$on('clear-filter',function(){
                   scope[attrs.ngModel] = false;
                });

                scope.$on('selected-filter',function(event,args){
                    //console.log('scope data',args);
                    //console.log('scope ', scope[attrs.ngModel]);
                });
            }
        }


  HTML:
<div class="inner-filter-section col-xs-3">
   <h5 class="nova-bold">Status</h5>
      <div class="outer-filter-section">
        <div class="filter-option" ng-repeat=" status in filterStatusItems">

<label data-filter-checkbox class="pull-left filter-checkbox" ng-model="active" data-ng-click="setFilterObj('status')"></label>
      <span class="options">{{status}}</span>
       </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filterStatusItems = ['Success','Pending','Failed','Running','Timeout','Flow Import','Shared','Credits'];
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your directive ? This is actually just a sort of match up of bad practices (Your uses of $on, $compile, no isolated scope to manage the bindings etc...). If you give me the purpose, i could clean it up for you at the same time i provide you a solution for your issue.

Comment: @Ved , you set the checkbox state in your scope and use it in html...
http://pastebin.com/2WfpQYvg
Sorry for the previous , forgot some basic syntax rules in that..

Is it clear ?

Comment: $on is used here to listen the event which I fire when I want to clear all selected checkboxes. Same $compile is here for compiling my directive.

Comment: @cafebabe1991 The link you posted. Is not opening. Let me see it first.

Comment: @Ved That's not how it should be done. You should manage bindings in a scope and just update them instead of working with $on.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2WfpQYvg , this is the link

Comment: @Okazari can you show me an example. I am not good in directives.

Comment: @Ved Yeah no prob, i just need to know the purpose of this directive. Wich behavior is it adding ?

Comment: @Okazari Requirement is using ng-repeat there will be multiple check boxes in view. whenever I will checked the box, the selected value will displayed as as  tag  in view. Now if I click on tag, respective checkbox should be unchecked

Comment: @Okazari this is how is used directive: <label data-filter-checkbox class="pull-left filter-checkbox" ng-model="active" data-ng-click="setFilterObj('status')"></label>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HRJPaivKSMMeojrTHKRB?p=preview)

I just didn't see the use of a directive here. If you have some other behavior to add feel free to correct me.

I simply init into the scope a collection that will hold the checkboxes references :

```
$scope.checkboxes = [];
```

On the input init i add an entry in the $scope.checkboxes collection

```
ng-init="checkboxes.push({status:status, value:false})"
```

I bind this value to the input. I use the $index to bind the right object to the input :

```
checkboxes[$index].value
```

Now the uncheck mechanics :

Here i only display the status with a property `value` as `true`

On click i just set the `value` as `false`

```
  <button ng-click="checkbox.value = false" ng-repeat="checkbox in (checkboxes | filter:{value:true}) ">
    {{checkbox.status}}<span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
  </button>
```

And that's pretty much all.

Hope it helped. If that was a mistake from me removing the directive just let me know that i can adapt a bit what i've done to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. It will be help me.

Comment: @Ved http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88793/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-32394898-how-to-unchecked-check-box-generated Sorry i was at lunch

Answer (score -1):

```
use ng-checked and set the value like true or false or assign ng-model value
```

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"><br/>
 <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master">
```

Comment: It is not what I asked.